# Possible for Category Base and Custom post Type to share the same slug/permalink?

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, permalinks

Rebuilding an author/writer website in WordPress.

I have a custom post type of `books`. Working OK.

I'd also like my category base to be `books`. Not working as yet.

So a book URL would be like:

`https://www.authorname.com/books/title`

And a category URL would be:

`https://www.authorname.com/books/fiction`

How can I achieve this?

> My workaround is a category URL like this (working using Category Base = `books/category`):
>
> `https://www.authorname.com/books/category/fiction`

Would prefer to add code in `functions.php` or `.htaccess` than use a plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not safe to use the `/books/` URL for both a category base and custom post type base. WordPress uses the URLs to determine what type of content to serve. If you've set up 2 different types of content at the same URL, it won't have any way to know which you're requesting, and if you end up with a book slug that's the same as a category slug, you'll really have conflicts.

To keep the URL types segregated but still logical, you could use URLS such as

CPT: `example.com/book/title-of-a-single-book`

Category: `example.com/books/category-name`

Or, perhaps something like

CPT: `example.com/books/title-of-a-single-book`

Category: `example.com/book-categories/category-name`

Or, continue using your workaround, `example.com/books/category/category-name`, and they will all appear to be under "books."

Comment: OK. I'll continue to use my current workaround. Thanks